What does "pull out" mean in "Democrats pulling out all the stops against RFK Jr."?
The title of https://thehill.com/homenews/campaign/4606148-rfk-jr-robert-f-kennedy-jr-nicole-shanahan-libertarian-democrats-joe-biden-donald-trump/ is:

Democrats pulling out all the stops against RFK Jr.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pullout defines
pull out
intransitive verb    
1
: LEAVE, DEPART
2
: WITHDRAW

which made me think that the Democrats were now confident enough to let RFK Jr. get on the ballets of the battle ground states. But I found myself wrong when reading the article.
Moreover "pull out" isn't transitive but used in such way in the title. Is that usage correct?
Is there a better expression (word or phrase) for this example? How about "pull on" (to hold onto and pull (something) repeatedly)?

"Pull out the stops" is an idiom.  It refers to an organ (musical instrument).  Organs work by pumping air through pipes.  You can push a "stop" into the controls to restrict the air, which makes the organ quieter.  Or you can pull out the stop, which lets more air go to the pipe and makes the organ louder. If you "pull out all the stops" you make the organ as loud as it can be.

See how the organist will pull the stop out.
The idiomatic use means do something at maximum effort:  "You should pull out all the stops in the week before the test." The example means that the Democrats are making a maximum effort to prevent RFK Jr. from being a candidate for President.

Different stops also produce different types of sound (high or low pitch, resemblance to other wind instruments).

It's a figure of speech, derived from church and theatre pipe organs. These have one or more keyboards (like that of a piano) and also the player can control the loudness and other things by pulling out round knobs called stops. If the player pulls out all the stops then they are playing very loudly (without any restraint). Thus the expression means to act with maximum effort and without restraint.




I strongly suspect that the number of native speakers who have seen organ stops is decreasing quite a lot.
